# Detecting Virtualbox from Docker

Tags: php, docker, environment-variables, virtualbox, docker-compose

My application using Docker should run slightly different in Ubuntu directly and in Windows + VirtualBox (without Vagrant).

Is it possible to detect if I'm in
`Ubuntu > Docker > Ubuntu` or in
`Windows > VirtualBox > Ubuntu > Docker > Ubuntu`?

**Why do I need this?**
I have PHP Symfony application and dev environment is very slow in Windows (each request takes more than 5 seconds) because of VirtualBox shared folders. I move out `var/cache` and `var/logs` to `/dev/shm/appname/` and everything becomes much faster. But developers who use Ubuntu don't need this - it works good even without this hack.

**My ideas**
Each developer can have it's own `docker-compose.yml` and set environment vars but now we share the same `docker-compose.yml` for most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be a stretch but when configuring paths in Symfony application kernel:

1. Call from PHP `df /some/application/file.php` and capture the mount point of a file (last column).
2. Call from PHP `mount | grep "$mount point" | grep "vboxsf" |wc -l`. If result is > 0 then you are using VirtualBox shared folders.

Comment: `mount | grep vboxsf` is cool. I can check if it's empty and decide whether it's Virtualbox